# Trying to unistall with wmic with RUNAS (scripting)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

Im trying to do a script for unistall and install a program as local admin from a domain user non-admin.

```
cmd /C runas /noprofile /user:LocalPC\localuser "wmic product where name="software" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

The command works well but when i try to do on a script doest work, either get a error, simply dont unistall the program

the code is

```
Set-Content "C:\script\unistall.bat -value 'wmic product where name="software" call uninstall /nointeractive'
cmd /C runas /noprofile /user:localpc\localuser "C:\script\unistall.bat"
```

any idea why the program dont unistall?

Comment: `Set-Content` is a `Powershell` command. Not really understanding what you are trying to do with that whole line of code.

Comment: Please revisit your question and use the [edit] facility to explain how internal powershell cmdlets are relevant to a [[tag:windows]] [[tag:batch-file]]/[[tag:cmd]] script, and what you're trying to achieve. And please note, regardless of how many hundreds of sites you find it on, the `call` method with `uninstall` does not accept parameters, so the is never a need to add an invalid/unused `/nointeractive` parameter.